Ignoring InsufficientResponseError in OSMNX
I have a list of 2000 names of localities.
I Use OSMNX Library with OpenStreetMaps to get the administrative boundaries of these localities.
Here is the link to the File:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g39dOk8kYGxOPGI-XhsmOps83azGluuF/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=104811936284098761818&rtpof=true&sd=true
The thing is, that in OpenStreetMaps, some of the localities are marked as points, not polygons, so i can not use the features_from_place option (because it can find only polygons)
Then I tried to use the ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf(thelist, which_result=1, by_osmid=False), where "thelist" contains my 2k locality names.
The same - i get Insufficient Response Error for the first Locality that cannot be found from the list.
Are there any ideas, how to make the OSMNX ignore the elements, that it could not find?
I Tried Googling, no results for this one...
Actually this is really frustrating, because it looks more of like a bug to me, rather a meaningful behaviour
UPDATE:
I have tried to find my localities by using the features_from_place, and I have some very strange results.
The documentation says that the features_from_place gives us any result only if there is a Polygon (or multipol) type of object.
So, I tried to use 2 types of query:
the code looks like:
dat = pd.read_excel('oren.xlsx')
lists = dat['Населённый пункт'][dat['Сроки'] =="-"].unique()
thelist=lists.tolist()
tags = {"name": thelist}
gdf = ox.features_from_place("Оренбургская Область", tags)
gdf2 = ox.features_from_place(thelist, {'addr:region':'Оренбургская Область'})

In this case, we find text "Оренбургская Область", for any element that has the tag 'Name' in it according to the given List (thelist)
And you know what? It found a lot of data, and also it found POINTs, Lines, and other types of objects, not just the Polygons or MPolygons
The second way to try this code:
gdf2 = ox.features_from_place(thelist, {'addr:region':'Оренбургская Область'})

And here, we try data, that has a tag "addr:region" equal to "Оренбургская Область" to check all of the elements in this region, that has the text from the list in it.
and this one gave the error.
Here is the full error text:

C:\Users\SSulyan\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx_overpass.py:254:
UserWarning: This area is 81 times your configured Overpass max query
area size. It will automatically be divided up into multiple
sub-queries accordingly. This may take a long time.   multi_poly_proj
= utils_geo._consolidate_subdivide_geometry(poly_proj)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In[191], line 3
1 tags = {"name": thelist}
2 gdf = ox.features_from_place("Оренбургская Область", tags)
----> 3 gdf2 = ox.features_from_place(thelist, {'addr:region':'Оренбургская Область'})
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\features.py:294, in
features_from_place(query, tags, which_result, buffer_dist)
289     gdf_place = geocoder.geocode_to_gdf(
290         query, which_result=which_result, buffer_dist=buffer_dist
291     )
292 elif isinstance(query, list):
293     # if it is a list, it contains multiple places to get
--> 294     gdf_place = geocoder.geocode_to_gdf(query, buffer_dist=buffer_dist)
295 else:  # pragma: no cover
296     msg = "query must be dict, string, or list of strings"
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\geocoder.py:139, in
geocode_to_gdf(query, which_result, by_osmid, buffer_dist)
137 gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
138 for q, wr in zip(query, which_result):
--> 139     gdf = pd.concat([gdf, _geocode_query_to_gdf(q, wr, by_osmid)])
141 # reset GeoDataFrame index and set its CRS
142 gdf = gdf.reset_index(drop=True)
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\geocoder.py:194, in
_geocode_query_to_gdf(query, which_result, by_osmid)
190     result = results[0]
192 elif which_result is None:
193     # else, if which_result=None, auto-select the first (Multi)Polygon
--> 194     result = _get_first_polygon(results, query)
196 elif len(results) >= which_result:
197     # else, if we got at least which_result results, choose that one
198     result = results[which_result - 1]
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\osmnx\geocoder.py:259, in
_get_first_polygon(results, query)
257 # if we never found a polygon, throw an error
258 msg = f"Nominatim could not geocode query {query!r} to a geometry of type (Multi)Polygon"
--> 259 raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Nominatim could not geocode query 'Чабла' to a geometry of
type (Multi)Polygon

The WHOLE CODE looks like this:
dat = pd.read_excel('oren.xlsx')
lists = dat['Населённый пункт'][dat['Сроки'] =="-"].unique()
thelist=lists.tolist()
tags = {"name": thelist}
gdf = ox.features_from_place("Оренбургская Область", tags)
gdf2 = ox.features_from_place(thelist, {'addr:region':'Оренбургская Область'})

UPDATE2:
I try This code:
ox.geocoder.geocode_to_gdf('W366775538', which_result=1, by_osmid=True)

So it gives me an error, that Nominatim can't find this ID, bit this ID is present in the OpenstreetMap (website)
Error

Can you provide the full traceback of this error? OSMnx can generate this error in multiple situations.

Seconding Nick's comment: this should be easily fixed if you provide a traceback and complete minimal reproducible code snippet.

Your code snippet isn't reproducible because it relies on an external file oren.xlsx

If I give you the File, would it be ok?
